# Creating a linked list by insertion at end mechanism

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am new to c++,and i am trying to implement data structure->linked list using c++, Program doesn't shows any error but its not working for more than one element,and also display_List() function is not working event though it is called in main function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data_;
    struct Node * link_;
};
struct Node * start = NULL;
void create_Node(int data)
{
    struct Node * temp,*pos;
    temp = new Node;
    temp->data_=data;
    temp->link_=NULL;
    if(start==NULL)
        start = temp;
    else
    {
        pos = start;
        while(pos->link_ != NULL)
        {
            pos=pos->link_;
        }
        pos->link_ = temp;
    }
}
void display_List()
{
    struct Node * Print;
    Print = start;
    while(Print->link_ != NULL || Print->link_==NULL)
    {
        cout << Print->data_;
        if(Print->link_!=NULL)
            cout<<"-->";
        Print = Print->link_;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int Data , no_of_Element;
    cout << "Enter the no_of_Element: "<<endl;
    cin >> no_of_Element;
    while (no_of_Element > 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter the Data to be inserted: "<<endl;
        cin >> Data;
        create_Node(Data);
        no_of_Element--;
    }
    display_List();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "i am trying to implement data structure->linked list" - *Why*? 1) C++ already has `std::list` and `std::forward_list` ready for you to use. 2) A linked list is just about the *worst* performing data structure you can ask a modern CPU to work with. -   I assume this is for learning purposes. Advice: Once you are done learning, throw away your code and just use what the standard library already provides (and, you probably just want a `std::vector`).

Answer (score 1):

```
void display_List()
{
    struct Node * Print;
    Print = start;
    while(Print->link_ != NULL)
    {
        cout << Print->data_ <<"-->";
    }
}
```

should be

```
void display_List()
{
    struct Node * Print;
    Print = start;
    while(Print != NULL)
    {
        cout << Print->data_ <<"-->";
        Print = Print->link_;
    }
}
```

Your loop stops too early because you are testing `Print->link_ != NULL` instead of `Print != NULL`. Also you never move onto the next item in the list because you didn't have `Print = Print->link_;`.

Also

```
if(start==NULL)
    start = temp;
else
    struct Node * pos;
    pos = start;
    while(pos->link_ != NULL)
    {
        pos=pos->link_;
    }
    pos->link_ = temp;
```

should be

```
if(start==NULL)
    start = temp;
else
{
    struct Node * pos;
    pos = start;
    while(pos->link_ != NULL)
    {
        pos=pos->link_;
    }
    pos->link_ = temp;
}
```

You forgot to add `{ }` round the else part of your if statement

There's an easy way to find these bugs (easier than posting to SO) which is to use a debugger to step through your code one line at a time. A debugger would have quickly found all three of the errors above, you should learn how to use one.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code.

1. Missing brackets for if statement while inserting.

   Change as following.

   ```
   if(start==NULL)
   {
       start = temp;
   }
   else
   {
       struct Node * pos;
       pos = start;
       while(pos->link_ != NULL)
       {
           pos=pos->link_;
       }
       pos->link_ = temp;
   }
   ```
2. your display function will lead to infinite loop since you are not incrementing the `Print` pointer.

   Change it to as following.

   ```
   while(Print != NULL)
   {
       cout << Print->data_ <<"-->";
       Print = Print->link_;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a number of issues with your code.

First off, in C++, you don't need to prefix the `struct` keyword onto the typename of a variable of structure type, like you do in C.

In `create_Node()`, your `else` is missing a required set of braces.

In `display_List()`, if the list is empty, your code has *undefined behavior* since `Print` will be NULL when dereferenced.  On the other hand, if the list has more than one node, the code will get stuck in an endless loop because you are not updating `Print` to point at the next node on each iteration.

In `main()`, you are leaking the allocated memory for the list before exiting.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data_;
    Node * link_;
};

Node *start = NULL;

void create_Node(int data)
{
    Node *temp;
    temp = new Node;
    temp->data_ = data;
    temp->link_ = NULL;
    if (start == NULL)
        start = temp;
    else
    { // <-- add this !
        Node *pos;
        pos = start;
        while (pos->link_ != NULL)
        {
            pos = pos->link_;
        }
        pos->link_ = temp;
    } // <-- add this!
}

void display_List()
{
    Node *Print;
    Print = start;
    while (Print != NULL) // <-- change to this!
    {
        cout << Print->data_ << "-->";
        Print = Print->link_; // <-- add this!
    }
}

void destroy_List() // <-- add this!
{
    Node *temp;
    temp = start;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        Node *next = temp->link_;
        delete temp;
        temp = next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int Data, no_of_Element;

    cout << "Enter the no_of_Element: " << endl;
    cin >> no_of_Element;

    while (no_of_Element > 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter the Data to be inserted: " << endl;
        cin >> Data;
        create_Node(Data);
        no_of_Element--;
    }

    display_List();
    destroy_List(); // <-- add this!

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, some of this code can be simplified further:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data_;
    Node *link_;

    Node(int data) : data_(data), link_(NULL) {}
};

Node *start = NULL;

void create_Node(int data)
{
    Node **cur = &start;
    while (*cur)
        cur = &((*cur)->link_);
    *cur = new Node(data);
}

void display_List()
{
    for(Node *cur = start; cur != NULL; cur = cur->link_)
        cout << cur->data_ << "-->";
}

void destroy_List()
{
    Node *next;
    for(Node *temp = start; temp != NULL; temp = next)
    {
        next = temp->link_;
        delete temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int Data, no_of_Element;

    cout << "Enter the no_of_Element: "<< endl;
    cin >> no_of_Element;

    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_Element; --i)
    {
        cout << "Enter the Data to be inserted: " << endl;
        cin >> Data;
        create_Node(Data);
    }

    display_List();
    destroy_List();

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, once you learn this, you should really switch to using [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) instead, or even [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) in C++11 and later.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list> // or <forward_list>

list<int> my_list; // or forward_list<int>

int main()
{
    int Data, no_of_Element;

    cout << "Enter the no_of_Element: "<< endl;
    cin >> no_of_Element;

    for (int i = 0; i < no_of_Element; --i)
    {
        cout << "Enter the Data to be inserted: " << endl;
        cin >> Data;
        my_list.push_back(Data);
    }

    for(list<int>::iterator iter = my_list.begin(); // or forward_list<int>
        iter != my_list.end();
        ++iter)
    {
        cout << iter->data_ << "-->";
    }

    /* or, in C++11 and later:
    for(auto data : my_list)
        cout << data << "-->";
    */

    return 0;
}
```